# form.is_valid() always returns false perhaps issue with "This field is required" error

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I am learning django. I am stuck with this problem.

The problem is that form.is_valid() always returns false.

I tried to debug and I think that the problem is because of "This field is required" error and I think that the field is file_name. I tried to resolve the issue but I am unable to do so.

Just to give a context of what I am trying to do -

I have created a form in which a user uploads a text file and selects a gender.

In the backend I want to save the name of the text file along with the gender in a model. The purpose of doing this is because when multiple users will use the application, I should know which user selected what gender so that I can produce the desired output.

Here is the link to my git repository -
[git repository](https://github.com/AnshulGupta22/auto_generation.git)

As I already said I am new to django and some help will be appreciated.

Comment: Read up how to ask questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include your code not send us to some repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fields in form are `fields = ['file_name','gender']` and in the template you have

```
<label for="myfile"> <b> Select a file: </b> </label> <br/>
<input type="file" name="document"> <br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
{{ form.gender }}
```

... fields `document` and `gender`, no `file_name`. Add `{{ form.file_name }}` to the template or, if you want to stick to manually writing code for input, file input with a name `file_name`. Input names need to match field names in form.

Also, read this: [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not saving the form. In your views line 24 you have

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TranscriptForm(request.POST)
        return HttpResponse(str(form.errors))
```

If you are posting you will always return there,therefore there is no check for `is_valid()`.

Same as line 60:

```
context = {'form': TranscriptForm()}
    return render(request, 'tutorial/upload.html', context)
```

you havent accessed/saved the form yet for it to be valid